# sqlite eval INNER JOIN on self duplicates v(*) entries

Tags: sql, sqlite, tcl

I have an SQLite database `db` and a view `pending_nodes`. To find `pending_subnet` - pending nodes whose upstream is also a pending node - I've prepared this statement:

```
  db eval {
    SELECT * FROM pending_nodes AS left
      INNER JOIN pending_nodes AS right ON left.process=right.upstream} v {
    parray v
    # do stuff...
  }
```

To my surprise `parray` gives me this result:

```
v(*)        = node process type upstream node process type upstream
v(node)     = 2
v(process)  = 6
v(type)     = reference
v(upstream) = 5
```

The printed data is as expected, but the `v(*)` list is duplicated. Looks weird and suspect I've done something wrong.

Q: What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try `left.*` to select only once

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it worked, but I wanted `right.*` ;-)

Comment: Good, it was fifty/fifty :)

Answer (score 1):

From @JoakimDanielson comment, selecting `*` from just one of tables (right) gives expected results:

```
SELECT right.* FROM pending_nodes AS left
  INNER JOIN pending_nodes AS right ON left.process=right.upstream
```